# Laravel - display users in foreach loop twice with ordered by date

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, foreach

I have a `users` table like this:

[image]

I would like to display a query, where every user is listed twice with different text (created_at / updated_at) and the date. The merged query should be ordered by date (created_at and updated_at).

##### Expected result

```
Zoey created at 2022-10-09 ...
Peter created at 2022-10-20 ...
Zoey updated at 2022-10-24 ...
Peter updated at 2022-10-31 ...
```

How to do that in Laravel 8? How should the `foreach` loop look like? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Laravel's [`union`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#unions) for this:

```
$createdBy = User::select('name', 'created_at as display_date', DB::raw("'created' as action"));

$users = Users::select('name', 'updated_at as display_date', DB::raw("'updated' as action"))
->union($createdBy)
->orderBy('display_date')
->get();
```

This will return a Collection of User models like so:

```
array:6 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "name" => "Zoey"
    "display_date" => "2022-10-19 18:46:50"
    "action" => "created"
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▼
    "name" => "Peter"
    "display_date" => "2022-10-20 18:47:00"
    "action" => "created"
  ]
  2 => array:3 [▼
    "name" => "Zoey"
    "display_date" => "2022-10-24 18:46:55"
    "action" => "updated"
  ]
  3 => array:3 [▼
    "name" => "Peter"
    "display_date" => "2022-10-31 18:47:06"
    "action" => "updated"
  ]
]
```

Then you can loop this single Collection:

```
@foreach($users as $user)
  {{ $user->name . ' ' . $user->action . ' at ' . $user->display_date }}
@endforeach
```

Output would be:

```
Zoey created at 2022-10-19 18:46:50
Peter created at 2022-10-20 18:47:00
Zoey updated at 2022-10-24 18:46:55
Peter updated at 2022-10-31 18:47:06
```

Also for reference, this would be the SQL Query executed:

```
SELECT name, created_at as display_date, 'created' as `action` FROM users
UNION
SELECT name, updated_at as display_date, 'updated' as `action` FROM users
ORDER BY display_date;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller(Using Eloquent ORM):

```
$users = User::get();
return view('your_view', compact('users'));
```

Then in your view file:

```
@foreach($users as $user)
{{ $user->name }} created at {{ $user->created_at }}
@endforeach

@foreach($users as $user)
{{ $user->name }} updated at {{ $user->updated_at }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: But how to sort all of them relied on both dates?

Comment: Check @TimLewis answer above.